# Spring-boot Whitelabel Error Page on debian with java version 1.8.0_40

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, deployment, spring-boot

I have spring boot application. After building it i get jar and it works on windows (java version 1.8.0_31). When it is deployed on debian server with java version 1.8.0_40 i get this error :

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon May 04 22:37:21 CEST 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp
```

Comment: Well it just states that the login.jsp can't be found. I assume there are other differences than just the java version. Most likely there are some issues in the application.properties that do work on Windows but lead to an error in Linux. How did you started the app on windows? Using java -jar?

Comment: Thre problem was beacuse when i ran it i wasn't project folder but in target. :)

Comment: getting same error. Project running smoothly on windows but on Linux environment it is throwing Whitelabel Error.